# SQL query question from someone with no SQL training

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL and have what I hope is a simple question. At the moment this query returns the same value for [quantity] if a [Lot No_] is in multiple [Bin codes]. I would like this query to sum the quantity per [bin code],

EDIT

It seems like the query sums up all entries in the warehouse table and returns that same quantity value for all the entries in the new table.

i.e currently if warehouse table has;

```
[Quantity]   [Bin code]  [Lot No_]
    40           A           x
   -35           A           x
    15           B           x
   -15           B           x
    5            C           x
    5            C           x
```

It gives the following table (when added with master$bin table)

```
[Quantity]   [Bincode]  [Lot No_] [Item No]
-------------------------------------------
 30            A            X         f1
 30            B            X         f2
 30            C            X         f3
```

Would like it to give the following;

```
[Quantity]   [Bincode]  [Lot No_] [Item No]
-------------------------------------------
 05            A            X         f1
 15            B            X         f2
 10            C            X         f3
```

Thanks in advance, this is the query;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_QV_Lots]
AS
    TRUNCATE TABLE [QV_Lots];

    INSERT INTO [QV lots]
    --select quantity, [Lot No_], [Bin Code], [Item No] from [QV Lots]
        SELECT
            SUM(Warehouse.Quantity) AS Quantity,
            BinContent.[Lot No_],
            BinContent.[Bin Code],
            Bincontent.[Item No_]
        FROM 
            [DB01].[LiveNLic].[dbo].[Master$Bin Content] AS BinContent
        INNER JOIN 
            [DB01].[LiveNLic].dbo.[Warehouse Entry] AS Warehouse ON Warehouse.[Lot No_] = BinContent.[Lot No_]
        WHERE 
            (BinContent.[Location Code] = 'A' OR BinContent.[Location Code] = 'B')
        GROUP BY 
            BinContent.[Lot No_], BinContent.[Bin Code], Bincontent.[Item No_]
```

Comment: And do you still want the Lot no returned?

Comment: Please post the schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements) and sample data, that lead to your actual result and should lead to your desired result. Please tag your DBMS too (I guess it's Microsoft SQL Server?).

Comment: @110179 ... Your query should be doing what you want.

Comment: @gordon linoff.. So it should be suminng quantity per lot per bin code in warehouse table? Because it seems to sum per lot and ignore the bin code, therefore if the same lot is in multiple bins (and has multiple entries with the same bin), the new table returns one entry per bin but the same quantity value (total of all lots) against each entry, and not give the individual bin quantity. – 110179 45 mins ago   delete

Comment: @110179 . . . You might want to set up a SQL Fiddle (or DB Fiddle or DB<>Fiddle or rextest) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query and your sample results are not compatible (one has three columns, one has four).  Your query is not what produces those results.

So, I suspect that you also have `quantity` or something else in the `group by`.

The following query should be calculating only the quantity associated with each row:

```
SELECT SUM(w.Quantity) AS Quantity,
       bc.[Lot No_], bc.[Bin Code]
FROM [DB01].[LiveNLic].[dbo].[Master$Bin Content] bc JOIN
     [DB01].[LiveNLic].dbo.[Warehouse Entry] w
     ON w.[Lot No_] = bc.[Lot No_]
WHERE bc.[Location Code] IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY bc.[Lot No_], bc.[Bin Code]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my post to hopefully make it more clear what I am after.